# Console output and file contents unmatched

Tags: c++, file-handling

I desire to output the file contents to the console using file handling. The variable marks is user defined.Now the contents are saved in the file correctly(I have attached a screenshot below). When I want to read the file the user defined functions gives inaccuarte output for the last two times.
**Contents of file:**

- Calculus 11
- FoP 22
- AP 33
- LCA 44
- Workshop 55
- Pak Studies 66
- English 77

**Output**

- Calculus 11
- FoP 22
- AP 33
- LCA 44
- Workshop 55
- Pak Studies 0
- English 1875928375

```
    int marks[7],i=0;
     string subject[7]={"Calculus","FoP","AP","LCA","Workshop","Pak Studies","English"};
     ifstream file3("Task4.txt");


     while(!file3.eof())
     {
         file3>>subject[i]>>marks[i];
         cout<<subject[i]<<" "<<marks[i]<<"\n";
         i++;

     }
     file3.close();
```

Comment: @sweenish can you please send the correct code

Comment: @sweenish No, they are reading and immediately cout-ing the contents.

What caught my eye here is that this wierd behavior only occurs after running into a two-word subject name. The >> operator always reads a single word (ie. until encountering a whitespace). Then everything could be offset. What puzzles me here is that the subject names are still read correctly. So I do not think this is going to work, but I would try to remove that one whitespace in "Pak studies"

Comment: @sweenish No, he's extracting from the file with operator>>. Also he's opening the file with std::ifstream, thus it's a bit tricky to write to the file.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Why eof in while loop...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: The problem is that the code is  reading word by word, a string, int, string, int and so on. On the next to last line there's two strings then a int, it's trying to extract "Studies" into a integer which fails.

Comment: I'd read the file line by line into a std::string and use find_last_of(' ') to split the string into a subject and a (integer) mark.

Comment: Good catch on the read and write. The `subject` array being pre-filled makes no sense then. I've deleted my initial comment.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems here:

- eof flag is only set on a failed read. This means by the time you check for it you already have a failed read.
- streams read one token at a time, meaning you do not read the entire *Pak Studies* string (just "Pak").
- then you attempt to read the second token into an integer ("Studies") which puts the stream in an error state. The stream is not in eof state though, so your loop continues, possibly traversing memory with i > 7 (and triggering undefined behavior).

The correct way (or rather "a more correct way") to do it:

- read input as long as you have input lines:

  ```
  std::string line;
  while(std::getline(file3, line))
  {
      // find position of last space
      int pos = line.rfind(' ');
      subject[i] = line.substr(0, pos - 1);
      mark[i] = std::stoi(line.substr(pos, std::npos));

      i++;
      if(i == 7)
          break;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be:

```
while (file3>>subject[i]>>marks[i])
{
    ++i;
    cout<<subject[i]<<" "<<marks[i]<<"\n";
}
```

See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons) for more details.

Comment: This code breaks the loop when reading the line "Pak Studies 44".

Comment: Is there something different about that text line?

Comment: The first extraction will place "Pak" into subject[i] and try to extract "Studies" into the integer marks[i] which fails. Then the stream is out of sync with the code.

Comment: It'd also be a tad better to increment i after std::cout is called ;)